Why `set` objects do not use `__newobj__` function to unpickle like other built-in container types?
I am recently writing a batch of customized container classes which are mostly inherited from built-in list, dict and set types, and I surprisingly encountered an error that the interpreter will raise an exception when copying instances of the class inherited from built-in set using copy module's copy and deepcopy functions, while other customized classes work fine.
an mwe
import copy

class SetBase(set):
    def __init__(self, iterable, name, master):
        super().__init__(iterable)
        self.name = name
        self.master = master
    
set_1 = SetBase([1, 2], name='set', master='master')
set_2 = copy.deepcopy(set_1)

The traceback message is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    set_2 = copy.deepcopy(set_1)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/copy.py", line 162, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/copy.py", line 253, in _reconstruct
    y = func(*args)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: SetBase.__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'name' and 'master'

SetBase is the class inherited from built-in set class, and it takes two more arguments name and master in __init__ method.
I searched around and finally found the cause of error lies in the __reduce_ex__ method of set class.
more explorations
Then I tried this:
>>> "".__reduce_ex__(5)
(<function __newobj__ at 0x104d41800>, (<class 'str'>, ''), None, None, None)
>>> [1,2].__reduce_ex__(5)
(<function __newobj__ at 0x104d41800>, (<class 'list'>,), None, <list_iterator object at 0x104c43df0>, None)
>>> {1:2}.__reduce_ex__(5)
(<function __newobj__ at 0x104d41800>, (<class 'dict'>,), None, None, <dict_itemiterator object at 0x104c5f830>)
>>> (1,2).__reduce_ex__(5)
(<function __newobj__ at 0x104d41800>, (<class 'tuple'>, (1, 2)), None, None, None)
>>> {1,2}.__reduce_ex__(5)
(<class 'set'>, ([1, 2],), None)

I've got a general knowledge that list, dict, tuple use __newobj__ function to unpickle and create copied instances while set does not, it uses set class.
The class derived from set class follows the pattern of set, so it explicitly calls the __init__ method after a copied instance is created. As the args are not fully given, an exception is raised.
wonderings
My question is what makes set so different in terms of __reduce_ex__ method? why not follow the __newobj__ way which seems more robust?
I've asked GPT about __reduce_ex__, it replied something about new-style class but not fully answered my question what differs set from others. Is there something underneath hindering the implementation of __reduce_ex__ of set objects?
possible fixes
For the above example, it is possible to fix such issue by simply overriding the __reduce__ method.
class SetBase(set):
    def __init__(self, iterable, name, master):
        super().__init__(iterable)
        self.name = name
        self.master = master

    def __reduce__(self):
        return (self.__class__, (list(self), self.name, self.master))

As in my real work practice, the customized container has more complex attributes and states to maintain, providing defaut values to additional arguments other than iterable is a workaround.

I wonder if this is purely a historical artifact, as set is relatively newer than the other types. (Introduced in 2.4, maybe, after the introduction of new-style classes in 2.2.)

Do you want a fix for the problem, or just an explanation of what and why?

I mainly wonder why. SInce I've found the cause of error, so my simple wordaround is to give default values to attached arguments. If there's more elegant way to fix it, it would be greatly appreciated to let me know. @quamrana

The other types you listed (str, list, dict, tuple) had native pickle support dating back to protocol 0.  Pretty much every other C coded type implemented afterwards has to have a __reduce__() method:  set, frozenset, bytearray, deque, defaultdict, OrderedDict, etc.

I am confused, does it mean later implemented class (e.g. set) behaves less robust than previous ones?? I was thinking __newobj__ is a newer way, but it's actually older? What's the consideration behind? @RaymondHettinger

Pickle has hard-wired fast-path special cases for list, dict, str.  For other builtin types, it uses __reduce__.  That answers one your questions about why some builtin types have __reduce__ and others don't.   It has nothing to do with being "robust".

What makes set different in terms of __reduce_ex__ method
set defines the method __reduce__, introduced in the initial implementation.
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/723d4d2f/Objects/setobject.c#L2403
dict and other built-in types do not.
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/82abe75e/Objects/dictobject.c#L4625-L4645
object.__reduce_ex__ prioritises __reduce__ if defined.
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7e6fcab/Objects/typeobject.c#L6946
>>> set.__reduce__
<method '__reduce__' of 'set' objects>
>>> dict.__reduce__
<method '__reduce__' of 'object' objects>

A more elegant way to fix deepcopy of set with additional args
You can override __reduce__ to revert to object.__reduce__:
class SetBase(set):
    def __init__(self, iterable, name, master):
        super().__init__(iterable)
        self.name = name
        self.master = master

    def __reduce__(self):
        return object.__reduce__(self)

>>> set_1 = SetBase([1, 2], name='set', master='master')
>>> set_1.__reduce__()
(<function _reconstructor at 0x10e75e8b0>, (<class '__main__.SetBase'>, <class 'set'>, {1, 2}), {'name': 'set', 'master': 'master'})
>>> set_1.__reduce_ex__(5)
(<function _reconstructor at 0x10e75e8b0>, (<class '__main__.SetBase'>, <class 'set'>, {1, 2}), {'name': 'set', 'master': 'master'})

>>> set_2 = copy.deepcopy(set_1)
>>> set_2.__reduce__()
(<function _reconstructor at 0x10e75e8b0>, (<class '__main__.SetBase'>, <class 'set'>, {1, 2}), {'name': 'set', 'master': 'master'})

Note that this uses _reconstructor, which is described as:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/faf7dfa6/Lib/copyreg.py#L39-L48

# Support for pickling new-style objects

def _reconstructor(cls, base, state):
    if base is object:
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
    else:
        obj = base.__new__(cls, state)
        if base.__init__ != object.__init__:
            base.__init__(obj, state)
    return obj


